# AWS fargate tutorial: cannot access webpage hosted in a container on ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am doing [this ECS fargate tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/getting-started-fargate.html). I followed prerequisites and each step but cannot access a webpage in step 4. The chrome browser error msg is like

```
This site can't be reached
container.public.ip.address took too long to respond.
　　　　　：
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I am not sure where I went wrong but it seems web server does not respond properly.

What I did so far is

- Increased resource(both cpu and memory)
- checked security group settings
- checked the service is supported in my region
- changed browser to access the webpage
- did a little search here and on the internet

but nothing works out.

Additional info: my region is ap-northeast-1.

Cound you give me some tips?

Comment: The fact that you "checked security group settings" doesn't really help here. What specifically are the security group settings?

Comment: I used the default sg which allows all inbound and outbound traffic.

Comment: @MarkB I made a mistake. [This doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/default-custom-security-groups.html) says default sg inbound rule allows access from network interface and ec2 which are associated with the default sg so access from outside vpc is not allowed. The tutorial works fine with another sg. Thanks for your comment!